# Script tags are not being read? javascript, angular. error file not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-not-found

Ok, so I am getting the following errors with my code....

```
GET file:///C:/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:19 GET file:///C:/bower_components/angular/angular-route.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:20 GET file:///C:/something.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:21 GET file:///C:/controller.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is with my script tags....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <a ui-sref="Page1">Page 1</a> | <a ui-sref="Page2">Page 2</a> | <a ui-sref="Nowhere">Nowhere</a>
    <hr />
    $state.current.templateUrl = {{main.$state.current.templateUrl}}
    <hr />

    <ui-view></ui-view>



        <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/something.js"></script>
        <script src="/controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not understanding what, exactly, is wrong here? my teacher is saying the syntax is correct so I am incredibly confused.

Comment: Are you loading the HTML file directly into your browser from disk? You're not using a web-server?

Comment: i've been using a web server, but this wasnt working on the server so i used to console to see what was going on error wise. my links in the document arent working and aren't clickable.

Comment: developing anything more complex than a `hello world` app should not be done using `file://` - I exaggerate, but real developers use a web server

Comment: is what you put in the script tags different if you are using a web server? i'm confused.

Comment: I have lite-server, but the project isn't working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using root-relative URIs `src="/controller.js"` so your browser will search from the root of whatever location your files are being served from instead of the current directory.

If you're loading HTML files from disk, at say `C:\Users\You\Project\Index.html` then the leading `/` means your browser will search `C:/controller.js` instead of `C:\Users\You\Project\Controller.js`.

Remove the leading slash, or serve your project using a webserver.

Comment: what about the two bower_component tags?

Comment: my issue is I did try to use the project on the server, the links arent working as links and was thinking this was why